# Relational database design with databases for status and types

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, referential-integrity

I am currently working with a database designed by someone else from my team and he uses a database design style I have not encountered before. I was wondering if the following design would be good practice since it seems kind of cumbersome to me.

There is a 'normal' database with user and business specific information. For the 'types' in this database, for example a `user`, there exists a table in two separate databases, namely `status` and `types`.

The status for a user is simply a name and a description (for example active or deleted).

The type for `users` is not really clear to me, but the table consists of a name, a description, a subset and a level field.

The cumbersome part would be the linking of these tables, since the they exist in different databases and the `user` table requires keys for both status and types (not enforceable via foreign keys).

Wouldn't it be better to have a simple boolean field to indicate whether the user is active and for types, if there will ever be any which is not likely, use inheritance?

Answer (score 1):

such these users may be beginner, so you can decide if your user status checked in code, for example when you login if query have this: `where status = 'active'` or like this so in this case you don't need a table and user status is static values you can include in your source code, also you should consider the language for these status if your system support multi languages. the same with the type field.

but if you don't need to check these flags in your code so there is no problem to leave them in table, but it will be nice in this case to give the user ability to add types or status after that.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question covers two different aspects:

**1) data cohesion and integrity** - referencing data from other tables which can or not be in the same database

**2) normalization** - do I need status and types in other tables or they can be incorporated in the same table?

1) If you are not working with huge data (at least tens of millions of records), I would recommend to replicate `status` and `types` tables in the "normal" database. This is particularly recommended, if data from there is rarely changed.

Doing this allows to apply referential constraints (FKs) and also have faster `JOIN`s.

2) Although it adds some complexity (extra table, defining constraints etc.), having your data normalized may bring some important advantages:

- flexibility - if a status or type is added, it just mean a simple insert in a table
- smaller tables - `users` table stores only some ids for status and type, not strings or hard to guess values (e.g. 0 - inactive, 1 - active etc.)
- easier maintenance - a type name is changed? Just update a record in a table

Normalized structures usually speak for themselves if designed properly (PKs, FKs, check constraints etc.) and allow separation of concerns (maybe you implement a designer for user types in some point in the future)

Usually, database separation should be done based on the activity type:

- operational (lots of `INSERT`s, `UPDATE`s, `DELETE`s beside `SELECT`s)
- reporting (mainly `SELECT`s)
- `ETL` destination - heavy `INSERT`s, `UPDATE`s etc.